# How could I remove space after framed figure's caption and text follows it?

Tags: captions, mdframed, framed

I have following code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}
\usepackage{enumitem,kantlipsum}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}
\title{hi}
\maketitle
\IEEEdisplaynontitleabstractindextext
\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle
\IEEEraisesectionheading{\section{Introduction}\label{sec:introduction}}

Blockchain
% Here first framed box fills complete first column.
\begin{framed}
 \scriptsize 
 Hello World. \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\  \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\  \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\
 \end{framed} 

% On the second framed box on top right column there is additional space shows up.
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{framed}
 \scriptsize 
 Hello World.
 \end{framed} 
 \vspace*{-5.0mm}
 \caption{Caption.} 
\end{figure}

Some text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text.
\end{document}
```

The output I get is:

[image]

You can see additional newline after the caption. I want to decrease the space right after the framed figure's caption, is it possible? Please note that I want to see my framed-box as a figure. The output I would like to have as follows:

[image]

**[Q]** How could I remove space after framed figure's caption and text follows it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you by adding a minimal compilable document (MWE) illustrating the issue.

Comment: Where does `\begin{verbatim}` end? What's your document class? "Compilable" means that it can he compiled...

Comment: See if replacing the `center` environment with the `\centering` directive is enough. `figure` adds vertical  spacing, and `center` adds another – this is too much.

Comment: I am sorry, I forget to add, right after `% Hello World.` but for experiment you can leave it as empty. Document class is: `\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}` @marmot

Comment: Please add all that to the code of your question.

Comment: I updated my answer, hope it works on your end. @marmot

Comment: I have removed `\center` or try with `\centering`but it did not helped @Bernard

Comment: Yes, I know, there's another parameter. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{framed}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{0ex}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\setlength{\OuterFrameSep}{0pt}
 \begin{framed}
 \scriptsize \bfseries
   \begin{verbatim}
    % Hello World.
   \end{verbatim}
 \end{framed}
  \caption{Caption.} \label{fig:sig}
\end{figure}
\vspace{-1ex}

Some text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

For the second code, same method: set `\OuterFrameSep` to 0, `\abovecaptionskip` to a smaller value than the default, and insert a negative vertical space *after* the caption:

```
\documentclass[10pt, journal, compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}
\usepackage{enumitem,kantlipsum}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}
\title{hi}
\maketitle
\IEEEdisplaynontitleabstractindextext
\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle
\IEEEraisesectionheading{\section{Introduction}\label{sec:introduction}}

Blockchain
% Here first framed box fills complete first column.
\begin{framed}
 \scriptsize
 Hello World. \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\
 \end{framed}

% On the second framed box on top right column there is additional space shows up.
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \setlength{\OuterFrameSep}{0pt}
    \setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{0pt}
\begin{framed}
 \scriptsize
 Hello World.
 \end{framed}
 \caption{Caption.}
\vspace*{-3ex}
\end{figure}
Some text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works! But when I am use two framed box right after, (1st one in on the complete first column and second one is on the top of the second column), which still causes the problem I do not know why.

Comment: Could you please have a look on my updated answer where I give the example with double columns. @Bernard

Comment: @alper: I've added a solution for the new case, with some explanations. Is it like you want?

Comment: Yes its golden. Thank you very much! Its out of question but right after `HelloWord` text in right top frame is it also possible to ignore the newline inside the frame? @Bernard

Comment: There's no newline: it's simply the spacing of text w.r.t. the frame. If you want to reduce it, you can try, say,  `\setlength{\FrameSep}{1ex}` (the default is `\fboxsep`) before `\begin{framed}`.

Comment: ` \setlength{\FrameSep}{1ex}` worked for top spacing but didn't for the below part. What could I do for below part ? @Bernard

Comment: Strange… As a work-around, you can add at the end of the environment  `\vspace{-some length}`.  Could you post the exact code in the framed environment which produces this problem?

Comment: Please see: https://gist.github.com/avatar-lavventura/4d9f7acbc5cdcaa089d9c9fb27c9414f

Comment: You can add `\vspace*{-\FrameSep}` after `\end{verbatim}`. I don't know the reason for this extra spacing. Maybe this is linked to the verbatim environment.

Comment: `\vspace*{-\FrameSep}` helped to remove extra spacing! But still ` \setlength{\FrameSep}{1ex}` does not decrease the spacing on the below part. Please see updated code: https://gist.github.com/avatar-lavventura/4d9f7acbc5cdcaa089d9c9fb27c9414f  . Should I ask it as a new question? @Bernard

Comment: Maybe. I've checked it's probably linked to verbatim. In the meanwhile, here is a work-around: 
`\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \setlength{\OuterFrameSep}{0pt}
    \setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\FrameSep}{0.6ex}
\begin{framed}
 {\scriptsize
  \begin{verbatim}
  event LogSetJob(address clusterAddress, string jobKey,
     uint32 index, uint startTime)
}
 \end{verbatim}
 }
 \vspace*{-\baselineskip}
 \end{framed}
  \caption{Caption.} \label{fig:sig}
\vspace*{-2ex}
\end{figure}`.